# How to "reset" auto-increment counter in mysql

Tags: mysql

If you have a couple of tables in mysql, with foreign keys ans stuff, and some auto-increment counters with some gaps (entries have been deleted in the "middle" of the table), is there any easy way to "fix" the counters so that there is not any gap?

So from id={1,10,11,40} to go to id={1,2,3,4}

Thx.

Comment: Is alright even your auto-increment is **NOT** in sequential order

Comment: Why is it a problem? Are you already reaching the limit of the auto_inc column?

Comment: I'm not reaching the limit but that's what bother me in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just update the keys you risk breaking referential integrity. So no, I'd say that short of writing a piece of software that goes over every record and updates ids, also updating those entities with foreign keys pointing to each record, it's not an easy "one command" task.

Also consider that external consumers of your data might have pointers to your information, so you need to think about the impact of just changing the keys arbitrarily.

Finally, what's your reason for wanting to have contiguous, gapless key assignment? it's usually not a problem to have gaps or "strange" key values. As long as the keys are indeed unique for each record, you're better off leaving them as they are, no matter what their value or sequence is.

Answer (score 2):

If this is NOT a live application, and you just want your rows to look pretty, delete the column and create a new one (with AUTO INCREMENT set, of course).

In real practice, you shouldn't expect your row IDs to be sequential.

Answer (score 1):

If you truncate the table, this will reset the counter. However, if you have rows in there already, it's not a very good idea to reset it back to 0 as you'll have duplicate ids.

Comment: That's not a problem, truncating the table will remove all of the existing rows and get rid of those pesky duplicate IDs

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the IDs with ALTER TABLE tblname AUTO_INCREMENT=1, but that only works with empty tables.

You could make a dump of the table without the IDs, delete all entries and use that command and then restore the data.

Note that this will break any referential integrity.