# Row decrementing/incrementing, in PHPMyadmin

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

I have a table in my database, ***newvehicles*** which has the following fields:

```
id (AUTO_INCREMENT)
make
model
doors
bodystyle
price
```

and this is an example:

```
1 Volkswagen Golf 2.0 GTI 3 Hatchback $39,490
2 Ford       Mondeo 2.3 Zetec 4 Sedan $54,450
3 BMW        3-Series 318i    4 Sedan $62,667
4 Renault    Clio     1.2 Base 3 Hatchback $22,686
5 Volvo      S60      3.2T SE 4 Sedan $49,460
6 BMW        5-Series 540i    4 Sedan $89,990
```

If I deleted, say, row 4, it would have rows 1, 2, 3, 5 and 6, and in order to reset the increment I use this code:

```
UPDATE automobiles SET id=id-1 WHERE id > 3
```

However, is there any way I can ***automatically*** get phpMyAdmin to reset the increment values for the id field (since it has an auto increment in) and I don't really want to keep using the above code every time.

By the way, not sure if this relevant, but the database is stored as InnoDB, just in case I have to do foreign keys for other databases that may link to it.

I'm fairly new to this, so would appreciate the help!

Comment: Why do you have to decrement that? It's very bad to do that, especially if you reference stuff in this table from other tables based on the id.

Comment: You don't have to bother auto_increment, is **auto increment** (always ++)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "reset" auto-increment counter in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298416/how-to-reset-auto-increment-counter-in-mysql)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, since I didn't ask the other question.

Answer (score 1):

The auto-increment value is used as a unique identifier. So later if you save that key elsewhere you will always pull that particular record.

If you want a number that is always sequential, I would suggest using a counter when you display them. I think that would save work in the long run.